# Victory Charts -- Break Line

Tags: javascript, victory-charts

Is it possible to break the plot line in a Victory Chart? I could do it by making two different plot lines of the same color, but I'm looking for an automatic way. I have data with a lot of zeroes, and I just want the curves. If I remove the zero values, the lines connect.

I have this. The lines connect at zero, underneath the axes origin:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function to create multiple data lines from an array with zeroes:

```
export function breakLine(buffer: any[], startTime: any) {
  let zeroCounter = 0;
  let signalCounter = 0;
  let curr: any[] = [];
  let result: any[] = [];
  buffer.forEach((value: any) => {
    // any value less than 20 will be considered a zero
    if (value.result[0] < 20) {
      zeroCounter++;
    } else {
      curr = [
        ...curr,
        {
          x: value.time - startTime,
          y: value.result[0],
        },
      ];
      signalCounter++;
      zeroCounter = 0;
    }

    // break line on 3 or more consecutive zeroes
    if (zeroCounter >= 3 && signalCounter > 0) {
      result = add(curr, result);
      zeroCounter = 0;
      signalCounter = 0;
      curr = [];
    }
  });
  // remaining in current after loop
  result = add(curr, result);
  return result.filter((plot: any) => plot.length > 0);
}
```

The I map a line for each nested array:

```
line1.map((data) =>
        <VictoryLine
        style={{
            data: { stroke: '#0000FF' },
            parent: { border: '1px solid #ccc' },
        }}
        data={data}
    />)
```